# How to refactor a complex JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, object, refactoring, prototype

I'm trying to refactor a bunch of methods that deconvolute an initial sequence into a final sequence. I can see three possible solutions, but I don't really understand what criteria I should use to choose between them.

To make the examples easier to digest, I've simplified the number of steps and the operations.

### Option 1 - Constructor function, set the methods in the prototype

```
function Deconvoluter(initialValue) {
  this.initialValue = initialValue
  this.finalValue = null
}

Deconvoluter.prototype = {
  deconvolute() {
    this.firstStep()
    this.secondStep()
    return this.finalValue
  },

  firstStep() {
    this.finalValue = this.initialValue + 1
  },

  secondStep() {
    this.finalValue = this.finalValue + 10
  }
}

d = new Deconvoluter(0)
d.deconvolute() // 11
```

### Option 2 - Regular function with private methods

```
function deconvolute2(initialValue) {
  this.initialValue = initialValue
  this.finalValue = null
  function firstStep() {
    this.finalValue = this.initialValue + 1
  }

  function secondStep() {
    this.finalValue = this.finalValue + 10
  }

  firstStep()
  secondStep()
  return this.finalValue
}

deconvolute2(0) // 11
```

### Option 3 - Regular function with method properties

```
function deconvolute3(initialValue) {
  this.initialValue = initialValue
  this.finalValue = null
  this.firstStep = function() {
    this.finalValue = this.initialValue + 1
  }

  this.secondStep = function() {
    this.finalValue = this.finalValue + 10
  }

  this.firstStep()
  this.secondStep()
  return this.finalValue
}

deconvolute3(0) // 11
```

Is choosing between these options a matter of personal preference or is one option better than the others? If so, are there situations where the other two would work better?

---

### Update

I've realized that the reason why I was drawn towards the third option is because I want to be able to access the intermediate steps. Would this then be a better implementation?

### Option 4 - Decorator pattern

```
function ComplexCalculation(initialValue) {
  this.initialValue = initialValue

  setFirstStepCalculation(this)
  setSecondStepCalculation(this)
  setFinalValue(this)
}

function setFirstStepCalculation(calculation) {
  // much longer calculation goes here
  calculation.firstStepCalculation = calculation.initialValue + 1
}

function setSecondStepCalculation(calculation) {
  // much longer calculation goes here
  calculation.secondStepCalculation = calculation.firstStepCalculation + 10
}

function setFinalValue(calculation) {
  // much longer calculation goes here
  calculation.finalValue = calculation.secondStepCalculation + 100
}

cc = new ComplexCalculation(0)
cc.secondStepCalculation // 11
cc.finalValue // 111
```

Answer (score 3):

There's really no value in using `this` in Option 2 and 3, and it's superfluous to initialize `finalValue` with `null`. I recommend this variant of option 2:

```
function deconvolute2(initialValue) {
    let finalValue;

    function firstStep() {
        finalValue = initialValue + 1
    }

    function secondStep() {
        finalValue = finalValue + 10
    }

    firstStep()
    secondStep()
    return finalValue
}

deconvolute2(0) // 11
```

Using the pattern of Option 1 makes sense if you want to have an object that holds a state (accessible through `this` and provides various methods to change this state.

So if, for example, you had not only a `deconvolute` method but also a `convolute` method, option 1 would be preferable.

The size and complexity of the `firstStep` and `secondStep` functions does not really matter.

Comment: Thanks! What do you see as a valid use case for using `this`? And would your answer change if `firstStep` and `secondStep` were 20 lines long?

Comment: What do you think about my updated Option 4. Would that be a reasonable option to also provide access to the intermediate values?

Comment: Hi @nachocab, IMO it would be better if you posted another question instead of continuing to edit this one and add more requests  Good luck!